# qt creator : no such a file or directory

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, include, qt-creator

hi i'm just trying to compile an easy project in qt

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

QPushButton bouton("Salut les Zéros, la forme ?");
bouton.show();

return app.exec();
}
```

but i have this error : /home/eid/test/easyprojet/main.cpp:1: error: QApplication: No such file or directory

can anyone help me ?

sorry for my english

Comment: your project file (*.pro) is wrong. Show how it looks like. Code is fine.

Comment: What is your Qt version ? 5.1 ? 5.0 ? 4.8 ?

Comment: @p1rox Probably we are both right. Maybe he has qt4 project and he tried to build it on top of qt5. In such case pro file has to be corrected a bit.

Comment: yes that was the probleme. thank you i found how to correct my mistake !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Qt5, it resides in , while in Qt4 it was .

In Qt5 you need to add `QT += widgets` to your .pro file.

Comment: Than you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It may be also because the project is not in the workspace of QT creator.
It happened with me before.
so,try to put the project in the workspace .

Comment: Ahem... what are workspaces in Qt Creator? Are there any? The question author's problem is definitely in pro-file, so I just wonder, what workspaces do you mean?

Comment: It is the folder that you chose to put and save your programs in when you setup the QT